# JavaScript цифры в рисунок звездочками/решетками

Tags: javascript

Никак не соображу, как преобразовать цифры в рисунок звездочками
К примеру: имеем 731
Нужно получить:

```html
 ####   ##     #  
    #  #  #  ###  
   #     #     #  
  #       #    #  
 #     #  #    #  
 #      ##   ####
```

Comment: К примеру каждую цифру обозначить рисунком(тегом с текстом), а потом сравнивать и выводить.

Comment: проблема в том, что в одной строке присутствуют символы от разных цифр.... и все это надо разбить

Comment: Решение в лоб: сохранить каждый символ как массив строк и затем выводить их построчно: http://jsfiddle.net/XelaNimed/8h1czt7q/

Comment: супер, то что надо, спасибо!